# prove that a antisymmetric and invertible matrix is congruent to another matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-congruences

let A be an antisymmetric and invertible matrix $A \in M_{2m}(\Bbb{R})$

1. prove that A is congruent to 
   $$
           \begin{pmatrix}
           0 & I_m  \\
           -I_m & 0  \\
           \end{pmatrix}
   $$
2. prove that $-A^{2}$ is a positive matrix

thx

Comment: 2) immediately follows from 1)